# Solr Fuzzy Search With Spaces

Tags: solr, solr-search

I would like to use the [Fuzzy Search Feature of Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/the-standard-query-parser.html#fuzzy-searches). In my dataset, I have one record that looks like this:

```
{
  "lastName": "John Doe"
}
```

I would like to perform multiple fuzzy searcheas with the following strings:

1. John D
2. John Do
3. John Doe
4. John Deo
5. John Xeo

I perform the query like this:

1. lastName:"John D"~
2. lastName:"John Do"~
3. lastName:"John Doe"~
4. lastName:"John Deo"~
5. lastName:"John Xeo"~

I expect, that query 1, 2, 3 and 4 return the record. Unfortunately, only query 3 returns it. As I understand from the [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/the-standard-query-parser.html#fuzzy-searches), it would be possible to specify the maximum number of edits allowed, when I don't specify something, the edit distance of 2 is used. I think I'm using the syntax incorrectly because if I take a look at my query it looks a lot like a [Proximity Search](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/the-standard-query-parser.html#proximity-searches).

But how can I fuzzy search for a string that contains spaces without using a proximity search?

Comment: What is the field type? If you want to perform fuzzy matches like that, you probably want to keep it as a single token and not indexed as separate tokens - BUT, there is a way around that - you can use the complex query parser - it'll allow you to specify `inOrder` and apply a fuzzy match against each separate token by itself. https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/other-parsers.html#complex-phrase-query-parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem seems to be, that I indeed executed a [Proximity Search](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/the-standard-query-parser.html#proximity-searches).

1. lastName:John\ D~
2. lastName:John\ Do~
3. lastName:John\ Doe~
4. lastName:John\ Deo~
5. lastName:John\ Xeo~

works exactly like I intend. I have to make sure, all the special characters listed here https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/the-standard-query-parser.html are escaped properly.